# Performing an aggregate operation (SUM) with the results of another query

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have two tables:

```
Bookings (uid INTEGER, in_date DATE, paxname TEXT, acnumber INTEGER)
```

and

```
Accounts (uid INTEGER, uidbooking INTEGER, acnumber INTEGER, amount_charged DOUBLE)
```

I would like to sum all the charges from the accounts table that belong to a subset of bookings.

The first select chooses the bookings in a certain perdiod of time...

```
Select bookings.uid, bookings.acnumber
WHERE bookings.status = 'checkedin' 
AND bookings.Indate > '2017-07-01'
```

Now the SECOND select should look for the charges of those bookings and SUM all the amounts of the accounts belonging to those previously selected bookings...

```
Select SUM(amount_charged) FROM Accounts WHERE acnumber = bookings.acnumber
```

So, how can I get all the results with the bookings uid, account number AND in the same row, the sum of the account charges... ?

Thnks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a join plus group syntax or the query as follows:

```
SELECT b.uid, b.acnumber,SUM(a.amount_charged) 
FROM bookings b, accounts a 
WHERE b.acnumber = a.acnumber 
AND b.status = 'checkedin' 
AND b.Indate > '2017-07-01'
GROUP BY b.uid,b.acnumber;
```

In the table bookings there is no acnumber, so maybe you have to exchange b.acnumber with b.account.

Comment: That seems ok.. the only drawback would be that the bookings which have their accounts empty (with no records) would not return zero, they just don't show up... (I would be expecting a null or zero).... but I guess could add some code on my side the check for that....

Comment: In this you need a LEFT or RIGHT join like this:`SELECT... FROM bookings b LEFT JOIN accounts a ON b.acnumber = a.acnumber WHERE b.status...`

Answer (score 2):

**The theory**

In SQL (not only in SQLite) these types of queries can be done in two different ways.

1. Join first, then aggregate (GROUP BY), or
2. Create a subquery, then aggregate only matching tuples.

While both methods will yield the same result, they might do it with significantly different performances. It will depend on the size of
the database and the query evaluation algorithms that the SQL engine uses

**The solution you need**

1. Using a join: I prefer explicit joins (make the code more readable)

```
    SELECT uid, acnumber, SUM(amount_charged) 
    FROM bookings join accounts USING(uid, acnumber)
    WHERE status = 'checkedin' AND b.Indate > '2017-07-01'
    GROUP BY uid, acnumber;
```

2. Using a subquery:

```
    WITH Matching AS (SELECT uid, acnumber FROM bookings 
                      WHERE status = 'checkedin' and Indate > '2017-07-01')
    SELECT uid, acnumber, SUM(amount_charged)
    FROM Accounts
    WHERE (uid, acnumber) IN Matching
    GROUP BY uid, acnumber;
```

In general, if the size of the subquery is large, this query will run slower than the join. But if the subquery returns only few tuples, it will typically be faster.